# How would I simplify this rational expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

**The original expression:**
$\frac{(x + 2)^{2} - (x + 2) - 20}{x^{2} - 9}$

I was taught to completely factor the numerator and the denominator before stating any non-permissible values, then to cancel out the common factors and simplifying.

**So here's what I did:**

$\frac{(x + 2)(x + 2) - (x + 2) - 20}{(x - 3)(x + 3)}$

**NPV:** $x ≠ \pm3$

I cannot simplify it anymore, since there are no common factors.

However, the textbook's answer is $\frac{x + 6}{x + 3}$, while their NPV matches mine.

Did I do something wrong, or is the textbook wrong? I don't understand.

Comment: `I  was taught to completely factor` It helps to first bring the numerator to the standard quadratic form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(x + 2)^{2} - (x + 2) - 20}{x^{2} - 9}=     \frac{(x + 2-5)(x + 2+4) }{x^{2} - 9} =      \frac{(x -3)(x+6)}{(x+3)(x-3)} =   \frac{(x+6)}{(x+3)}      $$